# How to install this c# extension in my vscode? I have been trying this for 5 hour

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[this is the screen shos everytime i try to install c# extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3hdL.png)

**I have been trying to install this c# extension in my vscode for long and it shows this error and says to manually download the VSIX file and instll. I have also done that but that shows update to version 1.25.0. which is very weird. This is the code below that shows in Log(Window) **

```
[2022-06-03 23:32:00.195] [renderer1] [error] [Extension Host] (node:1168) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\node_modules\find-parent-dir\package.json' of 'find-parent-dir.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-06-03 23:32:06.122] [renderer1] [error] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selection'): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selection')
    at CodeActionProvider.getInitializeFromCtorCommand (c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\out\src\codeActionProvider.js:165:33)
    at addInitalizeFromCtor (c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\out\src\codeActionProvider.js:15:28)
    at CodeActionProvider.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\out\src\codeActionProvider.js:19:9)
    at U.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:83:103152)
    at c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:83:131919
    at we._withAdapter (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:83:126001)
    at we.$provideCodeActions (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:83:131895)
    at s._doInvokeHandler (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:86:13828)
    at s._invokeHandler (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:86:13512)
    at s._receiveRequest (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:86:12121)
    at s._receiveOneMessage (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:86:10843)
    at c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:86:8949
    at m.invoke (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:145)
    at E.deliver (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:2265)
    at v.fire (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:1843)
    at l.fire (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:19001)
    at c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:102:34426
    at m.invoke (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:145)
    at E.deliver (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:2265)
    at v.fire (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:1843)
    at l.fire (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:19001)
    at r._receiveMessage (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:23582)
    at c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:21116
    at m.invoke (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:145)
    at E.deliver (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:2265)
    at v.fire (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:58:1843)
    at v.acceptChunk (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:15832)
    at c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:66:14962
    at Socket.R (c:\Users\jahed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:102:13798)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)

[2022-06-03 23:32:44.600] [renderer1] [error] [Extension Host] (node:7304) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\node_modules\find-parent-dir\package.json' of 'find-parent-dir.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-06-03 23:34:45.207] [renderer1] [error] [Extension Host] (node:19212) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'c:\Users\jahed\.vscode\extensions\jchannon.csharpextensions-1.3.1\node_modules\find-parent-dir\package.json' of 'find-parent-dir.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-06-04 00:12:17.128] [renderer1] [error] ["Download: XHR failed","    at q.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jahed/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:218799)","    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jahed/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:217417)"]
[2022-06-04 00:12:17.155] [renderer1] [error] XHR failed: Download: XHR failed
    at q.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jahed/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:218799)
    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jahed/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:217417)
```

Answer (score 0):

The XHR error at the bottom might indicate that this is a networking issue. Here are some possible solutions:

1. Are you using a special proxy? The solution might be to go to the [visual studio proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShLFq.png) and set them to the default settings.
2. If you have a VPN, turn it off(be sure to take company protocols in regard).
3. Reset your network (WiFi) and/or default the settings.